# Using sed in Alias with quotes and escape characters

Tags: apache, bash, sed, alias, profile

Ive got an alias to view my apache error log, which uses sed to format newline characters into newlines for better display. The following command works perfectly fine when entered via command line, but wont work as an alias. Every time I run this, I need to open my .profile, copy the contents of the alias, and paste it in command line.

```
tail -f /var/log/httpd/my-sandbox-error_log | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

alias:

```
alias elog="tail -f /var/log/httpd/my-sandbox-error_log | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/g'"
```

Ive tried a number of approaches, have swapped the quotation characters, and experimented with escape characters a'plenty. It seems I can never get my alias to make use of the sed search/replace (error log is tailed, with no newline formatting). Im sure there is something trivial missing, to which I am naive. I am not a unix/linux expert.

Can anyone enlighten me as to why this does not work as an alias?

Comment: What if you define the alias in the command line? Maybe it is just a matter of adding it to your `~/.bashrc` and then sourcing it.

Comment: Defining the alias in the command line has the same effect (I first removed it from my .profile and re-sourced it): the tail on my error log runs, but the newlines arent formatted at all. I dont believe the issue lies within where the alias is defined, and I "source ~/.profile" for every one of the many tens of times Ive attempted to fiddle with the alias. Just for the sake of your comment, I removed it from .profile and placed in .bashrc, and still has the same exact effect - tail runs but no formatting. Again, running the same command on command line, without an alias, works as expected.

Comment: Can you try with `alias elog="tail -f /var/log/httpd/my-sandbox-error_log | sed -e 's/\\n/\'$'\n/g'"` ?

Comment: @damienfrancois thanks but no dice - still same unformatted output. (for the record I gave the alias a slightly different name, and did "source ~/.profile" before running the new alias)

Comment: Pitty.. Works here (MacOS) If you replace with something else than a newline (a simple char or word), does it work ?

Comment: Have you tried to execute "alias" on your Linux to find which commands you have aliased OK?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you did `set -x`, `echo alias elog=..`, `alias elog` or otherwise got bash to write the result back to you, you'd see why it isn't working. `\\` in double quotes becomes `\`.

The rule of thumb is that if you have to ask, you've exceeded the usefulness of an alias. Use a function instead:

```
elog() {
    tail -f /var/log/httpd/my-sandbox-error_log | sed -e 's/\\n/\n/g'
}
```

This way you don't need any additional escaping.

Comment: thanks so much! All I had to do was add an additional slash to signify the escape char (alias elog="tail -f /var/log/httpd/my-sandbox-error_log | sed -e 's/\\\n/\n/g'") and it works as expected.